# find a polynomial whose roots are inverse of squares of roots of $x^3+px+q$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Question is :

Given a polynomial $f(x)=x^3+px+q\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ find a polynomial whose roots are inverse of sqares of roots of $f(x)$

Supposing $a,b,c$ as roots of $f(x)$ we have :

- $a+b+c=0$
- $ab+bc+ca=p$
- $abc=-q$

Now i need to know what

- $\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}$
- $\dfrac{1}{a^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{a^2}$
- $\dfrac{1}{(abc)^2}$

All i have to do is use $(a+b+c)^2$ formula and others and conclude what those sums,products are.. I am fairly comfortable with that...

But then, this question was from a Galois theory course.. So, i some how guess there is a better way to do this...

Can some one suggest something..

Comment: Reinterpret your answer in terms of symmetric polynomials in three variables.

Comment: @suresh :  I am sorry, I could not understand your idea...

Comment: The coefficients of any polynomial equation can be expressed as a symmetric polynomial in its roots. Now we can construct a new polynomial with roots $a^2,b^2,c^2$ -- the coefficients of which can be expressed in terms of $p$ and $q$. Then, replace $x\rightarrow 1/x$ to obtain the required polynomial as Michael has shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $x^3+px-q$ has roots $-a,-b,-c$.
- $(x^3+px+q)(x^3+px-q)$ has roots $a,b,c,-a,-b,-c$.
- $x^3+2px^2+p^2x-q^2$ has roots $a^2,b^2,c^2$.
- $1+2px+p^2x^2-q^2x^3$ has roots $1/a^2,1/b^2,1/c^2$.

Comment: I think this is  what i am looking for.... i understood third and fourth lines but how does first and second line helps?

Comment: You don't have to look at the symmetric polynomials separately.  The answer drops out automatically.

Comment: I am sorry.. I did not understand your comment...

Comment: Instead of calculating the symmetric polynomials, I calculated $f(x)f(-x)$, which I think is simpler.

Comment: I am not sure how does $f(x)f(-x)$ works... could you please elaborate it...

Comment: $f(x)f(-x)=(x^3+px+q)((-x)^3+p(-x)+q)=(x^3+px+q)(q-px-x^3)=q^2-(x^3+px)^2=q^2-p^2x^2-2px^4-x^6$ is a polynomial in $x^2$, and is zero whenever $x^2=a^2,b^2,c^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with: $\dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} + \dfrac{1}{c^2} = \dfrac{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}{a^2b^2c^2} = \dfrac{(ab+bc+ca)^2 - 2abc(a+b+c)}{(abc)^2} = \dfrac{p^2 - 0}{(-q)^2} = \dfrac{p^2}{q^2}$.

Comment: I can do in this way... you did not understood my question i guess... I am looking for a less laborious way...

Comment: this is perhaps the quickest way....

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
0 = (a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + ac + bc) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2p
$$
Thus
$$
\dfrac{1}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{1}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{1}{a^2b^2} = \dfrac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{a^2b^2c^2} = -\dfrac{2p}{q^2}
$$

Comment: I can do in this way... you did not understood my question i guess... I am looking for a less laborious way...

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered by Mr.Michael But then it is not complete answer..

So, Just for my convenience I would write it explicitly...

Given a polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with roots $a,b,c$ we need to find  a poly.  whose roots are $\dfrac{1}{a^2},\dfrac{1}{b^2},\dfrac{1}{c^2}$

Given that $f(x)=x^3+px+q$ with roots $a,b,c$ . So, we have :

- $a+b+c=0$
- $ab+bc+ca=p$
- $abc=-q$

With this we would find polynomial with roots $-a,-b,-c$. For that we need to know :

- $(-a)+(-b)+(-c)=-(a+b+c)=0$
- $(-a)(-b)+(-b)(-c)+(-c)(-a)=ab+bc+ca=p$
- $(-a)(-b)(-c)=-abc=q$

So, polynomial with roots $-a,-b,-c$ is $g(x)=x^3+px-q$

So, polynomial with roots $a,b,c,-a,-b,-c$ is  :

$$(x^3+px+q)(x^3+px-q)=x^6+2px^4+p^2x^2-q^2$$

Now we see that $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3+px+q$ and $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=x^3+px-q$

So, we have $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$$
$$=(x^3+px+q)(x^3+px-q)=x^6+2px^4+p^2x^2-q^2$$

i.e., $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=(x-a)(x+a)(x-b)(x+b)(x-c)(x+c)$$
$$=(x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)(x^2-c^2)=x^6+2px^4+p^2x^2-q^2$$

i.e., $$(x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)(x^2-c^2)=x^6+2px^4+p^2x^2-q^2$$

So, to get polynomial with roots $a^2,b^2,c^2$ we replace $x^2$ with $y$

polynomial with roots $a^2,b^2,c^2$ is $y^3+2py^2+p^2y-q^2$

Polynomial with roots $\dfrac{1}{a^2},\dfrac{1}{b^2},\dfrac{1}{c^2}$ is $-q^2x^3+p^2y^2+2py+1$

So, the polynomial that i need is $g(x)=-q^2x^3+p^2y^2+2py+1$