# Polynomial identities in a splitting field (Cardano's method)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, roots

Let $ P(X) = X^3 + pX + q $

We look at  $ P = (X- \alpha)(X- \beta)(X - \gamma) $
  it's factorization in L[X] (with L a splitting field of P)

Show that $ \alpha ^2 + \beta ^2 + \gamma^2 = -2p $ and that $ \alpha ^2 \beta ^2+ \beta ^2 \gamma^2 + \alpha ^2 \gamma^2 = p^2 $

Answer (score 3):

More generally, it is in principle easy to find the polynomial $Q$ whose roots are a rational function $g(x)/h(x)$ of the roots of a given polynomial $P$:
$$
Q(y)=\operatorname{Res}_x(y\,h(x)-g(x),P(x))
$$
This is called a [polynomial transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_transformation#Transformation_by_a_rational_function).

For $P(x) = x^3 + px + q$ and $g(x)=x^2, h(x)=1$, we get (using [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5By-x%5E2,+x%5E3+%2B+p+x+%2B+q,x%5D))
$$
Q(y)=\operatorname{Res}_x(y-x^2,x^3 + px + q)
= y^3 + 2 p y^2 + p^2 y  - q^2 
$$
and the result follows by Vieta's formulas.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872264/find-a-polynomial-whose-roots-are-inverse-of-squares-of-roots-of-x3pxq.

Answer (score 2):

$$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)=0-2p=-2p$$
$$\alpha^2\beta^2+\alpha^2\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma^2=(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)^2-2\alpha\beta\gamma(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=p^2-0=p^2$$